# Putting my edit-text and button in the middle of my layout

Tags: android, layout, center

I have a login page and 3 items on this login page that are currently at the top of the page. I want this items to be at the middle of the page, instead of the position it is at the top. This is the code am currently using:-

[image]

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

<!-- Login progress -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_status_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="@string/login_progress_signing_in"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Login form -->

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/LoginFormContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
            android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
            android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="32dp"
            android:paddingRight="32dp"
            android:text="@string/action_sign_in_register" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</merge>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set to your `LinearLayout`

```
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
```

### Corrected:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

<!-- Login progress -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_status_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="login_progress_signing_in"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Login form -->

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="prompt_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="prompt_password"
            android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
            android:imeActionLabel="action_sign_in_short"
            android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="32dp"
            android:paddingRight="32dp"
            android:text="action_sign_in_register" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</merge>
```

### Output:

### [image: OutPut:]

Comment: how should i use it in my code. i seem to have tried what you stated

Answer (score 0):

```
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
```

For the one under ScrollView `<LinearLayout style="@style/LoginFormContainer" android:orientation="vertical">` Add this line `android:layout_gravity="center"` for linearlayout just below scrollview

Comment: which linearlayout is this for. is it for the login progress or login form

Comment: For the one under ScrollView                                        <LinearLayout
        style="@style/LoginFormContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical" >                                                                    Add this line android:layout_gravity="center" for linearlayout just below scrollview

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Set LoginFormContainer layout width as match_parent and height as wrap_content and layout_gravity as center of ScrollView .

```
<LinearLayout
   style="@style/LoginFormContainer"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center">
```

Answer (score 0):

just edit you code

```
<LinearLayout
        style="@style/LoginFormContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

by

```
<LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```